# Unable to verify Azure AD token with NestJS application

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-active-directory, nestjs, passport.js

I'm trying to verify **Azure AD** token with my **NestJS** backend application. I'm logging to Azure AD using *React* frontend application and, for now, grab access_token from the response manually. Then I have this guard in *NestJS*:

```
@Injectable()
export class AzureADStrategy extends PassportStrategy(
  BearerStrategy,
  'azure-ad',
) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      identityMetadata: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantID}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`,
      clientID,
      clientSecret,
      loggingLevel: 'debug',
      loggingNoPII: false
    });
  }

  async validate(response: any) {
    console.log(response);
  }
}

export const AzureGuard = AuthGuard('azure-ad');
```

When i apply it on some endpoint i'm trying to fetch this URL, like:

```
curl localhost:9000/test --header 'Authorization: Bearer xyz'
```

But i'm not able to authenticate and i get this error log:

```
{"name":"AzureAD: Bearer Strategy","hostname":"<hostname>","pid":1713974,"level":30,"msg":"authentication failed due to: invalid signature","time":"2022-11-03T13:00:51.213Z","v":0}
```

How should i configure it to make it work?

Comment: I'm assuming you've been able to login ok and then pass the details to the API. On validate, this is what i have and works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've been able to login ok and then pass the details to the API and you're user/s are registered under the APP.

On validate, this is what i have and works fine.

```
  async validate(data) {
    return data;
  }
```

This is the example i followed to get it working - https://medium.com/adidoescode/azure-ad-for-user-authentication-with-vue-and-nestjs-4dab3e96d240

Answer (score 0):

I'm also facing this same issue. because the access token contains the nonce(check your access token at https://jwt.io/).

[image]

1. remove the default "Microsoft Graph" permission from your application.
2. Create a new scope for your application. Scopes define the specific permissions your application requires.
3. Add the newly created scope to your application's API permissions.

kindly follow this example, I covered these all in my article- https://medium.com/@gnanabillian/integrating-single-sign-on-sso-with-azure-active-directory-azure-ad-in-nestjs-210b07e7420d